# Routing to Js file with CodeIgniter4

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Let say i have this Public Folder inside the folder of `iot-code-igniter\public\style`

[image]

And i have file `data.php` inside folder `iot-code-igniter\app\Views`
[image]

here the code that i tried to call the **JS**,**CSS**,and **data.php** and it's doesn't work, below is **index.php** :

```
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="../../public/style/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="../../public/style/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="../../public/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var refreshid = setInterval(function(){
            $('#grafik').load('/data.php');
        }, 1000);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 24px;">
        <h3>Grafik Sensor</h3>
        <p>(Result data)</p>
    </div>

    <!-- tempat grafik -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container" id="grafik" style="width:80%; text-align:center;"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Question :**

1. How i can call the *src* file inside the head?
2. How i can load the *data.php* to render/extend it?

Comment: Better study each question separately and then decide how to contribute (instead of making one contribution mixing two things). It's perhaps easier to learn about 1. first and when understood and solved, then take care about 2. - just my two cents.

Comment: actually i know how to routing it (question 1) and i successfully to route it with normal Php file structure, but after i migrating to Codeigniter4 i have no idea that there will be a different method to use it. @hakre

Comment: In principle it works the same as with plain PHP. But you have to consider the actual URLs in action, e.g. the URL of the page in the browser as all URLs in the HTML document (like src of style) are resolved to that document URL (for more details look for the _document base URL_ and _URL resolution_ in HTML and HTTP URL RFCs / specs / documents). Then check which URLs Codeigniter creates for the pages and the Codeigniter docs of the specific version in use for something like URL-helper or link-helper or the like. Don't know Codeigniter4, perhaps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```html
<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="../public/style/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="../public/style/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="../public/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: if i do `../` for once only, the Public folder still unreachable, can you explain more? thanks

Comment: Is this file  data.php in this folder  Views

Comment: yes as i write above. `data.php` was placed inside `Views` folder

Comment: If she works from this file, make  copy to links

Answer (score 0):

The public folder is the root folder for the web browser, and your paths need to be absolute or relative to that folder.

You need to remove any prefix to `public`.

`<script type = "text/javascript" src="/style/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

In the folder public create assets/css/... and assets/js/...

```html
<link 
  href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/material-icons.css'); ?>" 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css"
>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```